# PHP shorthand if echo else assign variable

Tags: php

I want to write this in one line if possible:

```
if ($some_var === true) {
 $return .= $input;
} else {
 echo $input;
}
```

Obviously I don't want this:
`if ($some_var === true) { $return .= $input; } else { echo $input; }`
but a shorter version of it.

I looked at other answers but I only find the echo (expression) ? true : false; statements. I don't want to echo on the true, only on the false.

Comment: Why?  The code as it stands is clear and easy to maintain.

Comment: Just to save some writing and code size

Comment: But you've already written it like this - how does it save time to write it again? Code is read back far more often than it's written down, and trying to fit all of this into a single line is going to cost you more time in future trying to remember how it works (or why you decided to fit it all into one line).

Comment: There is a way to do this with a one-line ternary but I will refrain from posting it as it brings absolutely no benefit (except save 3 lines, which isn't at all a good measure of solid/maintainable code).

Comment: Ask yourself *why* you don't just want to fit the existing if-statement onto one line. If the answer is "because it's harder to read", then you've just answered your own question.

Comment: Since I have this part of the code around 50 times in my script, I thought that it will reduce the lines of the code by some... Thanks anyway for the feedback

Comment: Repeated code is a candidate for a function :-) and then you call your function with just one line of code.

Answer (score -3):

```
$some_var = true;
$input = 'abc';
$return = '123';
echo ($some_var === true) ? ($return .= $input) : ($input);
```

Comment: This gives me a FATAL ERROR syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line number

Comment: Updated my answer above. Please, give it a try.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.